# $(document).ready(function() { Rails Turbo-links

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, turbolinks

Having problems running this with turbo-links...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 var n = '#nav', no = 'nav-open';
  $('#nav-menu').click(function() {
    if ($(n).hasClass(no)) {
        $(n).animate({height:0},300);
        setTimeout(function(){
            $(n).removeClass(no).removeAttr('style');
        },320);
    }
    else {
        var newH = $(n).css('height','auto').height()
            ;
        $(n).height(0).animate({height:newH},300);
        setTimeout(function(){
            $(n).addClass(no).removeAttr('style');
        },320);
    }
 });
});
```

I tried this without any luck:

```
var ready;
ready = function() {

 ...your javascript goes here...

};

$(document).ready(ready);
$(document).on('page:load', ready);
```

Sorry, I'm useless with Javascript!

Comment: Why does this not work for you? Have you checked the console for errors?

Comment: Your code works http://jsfiddle.net/mr4C4/

Comment: @max, the problem isn't that the code doesn't work - it's because of TurboLinks, which basically keeps it loaded even if you go onto a different page; confusing the hell out of JS

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, I would recommend using [jQuery-Turbolinks](https://github.com/kossnocorp/jquery.turbolinks), which is a gem you install to make JS work with Turbolinks

We had a similar problem to yourself, in that we'd have

```
$(document).ready(function() {});
```

and it wouldn't fire -- and it was caused by Turbolinks loading the document once, and then tricking JS into thinking that it's not reloaded

I'd try installing the gem & seeing if it works:

Gemfile:

```
gem 'jquery-turbolinks'
Add it to your JavaScript manifest file, in this order:

//= require jquery
//= require jquery.turbolinks
//
// ... your other scripts here ...
//
//= require turbolinks
```

Comment: jquery.turbolinks should not be used for new code - it is a wrapper to make existing legacy code with with the new turbolinks framework.

Comment: then you should have written your new code around turbolinks, instead of putting this hack in.

Comment: Ok thanks for that! I'll keep that in mind for next time. However, I have contributed my fix, which I feel will help resolve the OP's issue directly

Answer (score 0):

Add `()` on your last two lines to ask them to execute

```
$(document).ready(ready());
$(document).on('page:load', ready());
```

Explanation: `ready` is a variable representing a function defined by you. If you call its name `ready`, it will return the function definition. If you call it to execute, you need to add `()`.

Comment: I tried this without any luck:

`var ready;
ready = function() {
 var n = '#nav', no = 'nav-open';
 $('#nav-menu').click(function() {
  if ($(n).hasClass(no)) {
   $(n).animate({height:0},300);
   setTimeout(function(){
    $(n).removeClass(no).removeAttr('style');
   },320);
  }
  else {
   var newH = $(n).css('height','auto').height()
    ;
   $(n).height(0).animate({height:newH},300);
   setTimeout(function(){
    $(n).addClass(no).removeAttr('style');
   },320);
  }
 });
};
$(document).ready(ready());
$(document).on('page:load', ready());`

Comment: @owenob1, I forked Max's fiddle and revised as per the new structure.  It works under jQuery's ready. http://jsfiddle.net/billychan/4Zgug/

Comment: Please don't say this won't work in Rails with TurboLinks, it just doesn't work in your specific project. I have similar methods working nicely. Also, please don't just say it doesn't work, nobody here has access to your project and can debug that for you, it's your turn to provide specific error message when meeting problem.